# Site Cookies - Are there any security issues?

Tags: php, security, cookies

I am currently trying to think of a way to keep a user logged in for a certain amount of time. I come across the use of site cookies. My dev-environment as an example is `PHP`.

`addcookie('name', 'value', time() + 3600, '/');`

I understand that you can generate a large, unique key as a value for each user which is stored in the Database, for reference for security, and then the only way really to manipulate a user would be to session steal using Cross-Site Scripting.

I am curious to know, due the the final parameter in the `addcookie()` - where the `/` is present in the example - is it possible for someone to set-up their own domain and actually add their own cookie to another domain?

I am not sure whether to strip the key before querying it in the Database because I am unsure whether this vulnerability exists - or any like such.

Any references would be great because Security is something that I find interesting, especially unauthorised access prevention.

I merely know anything about Cookie Poisoning and would love to understand more and how to prevent things or build an infrastructure that prevents the attack.

Edit: I am not asking how to `Secure` anything, just what Cookie Poisoning is and maybe ways that can be used to prevent people actually being able to do this (even if it's just tips!)

Comment: As long as the domain of the cookie is set, the only way an attacked can `cookie poison` is by either XSS or access to the computer storing the cookie.

Comment: See, I've been researching and what I am seeing is the exact opposite. Apparently, `cookies` can be `edited` using something named a `data tamper` ? This is used to change cart prices in an attempt to trick the infrastructure about the price to get it for nothing. @aron9forever

Comment: To make sure I understand, the scenario you're describing is 1)I visit your website, get a cookie 2)I visit another website that tampers with your cookie 3)I visit your website again and something goes wrong. If that's correct then no, that's not possible. First of all because the second website can't access your cookie, and even scripts sent by the second website can't access your cookie due to security implementations in modern browsers. This phenomenon is called "cross site cooking"

Comment: However my comment implies that you don't have XSS vulnerabilities in your website. Because if you do, then an attacked can access and modify a cookie. Since the script is coming from your domain, the browser grants access to the cookie.

Comment: See, this is the situation. I am un-aware of how the vulnerability works, how would a second - malicious - site 'tamper' with my cookie? This leaves me to think that a second site could also add a cookie @aron9forever

Comment: OH, I understand now! I assume they exploit using the XSS vulnerability in your site which then alters there cookies? Maybe then if, for example, a cookie wasn't stripped before query, its likely of a SQLi injection? Wow, this all makes sense now. That's crazy how it works. I appreciate this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned  session hijacking through cross site scripting (XSS) is common.

To prevent   XSS  you should always filter and escape all user session values before printing them to screen. However some bugs may slip through or a piece of legacy code might be vulnerable so it makes sense to also make use of browser protections against XSS.

By specifying the HttpOnly flag when setting the session cookie you can tell a users browser not to expose the cookie to client side scripting such as JavaScript. This makes it harder for an attacker to hijack the session ID and masquerade as the effected user.

```
 session.cookie_httponly = 1
```

It is also a good idea to make sure that PHP only uses cookies for sessions and disallow session ID passing as a GET parameter:

```
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

Another important way to increase the security of PHP sessions in your application is to install an SSL certificate on the web server and force all user interactions to occur over HTTPS only.

Helpfully PHP has one ini setting to assist you in ensuring session cookies are only sent over secure connections:

```
 session.cookie_secure = 1
```

Ref:https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2013/05/improve-php-session-cookie-security/

Comment: That's a great source of information and perfectly explained! Regarding a login key, would it best to strip the characters out of it if I am passing it directly into a query? Because if I read that correctly, I assume a second website could `alter` the cookie?

Comment: @ KyleE4K you are right.Strip is a good option.You can read more at: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/

Comment: So crazy how something so little to be missed can cause such major vulnerabilities! Thanks for all the help!